# How to change react-router-component context root

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, url-routing, contextpath, react-router-component

I changed the web application deployment context path from / to /foo in web.xml, and react-router-component (not react-router) stopped working, giving the following error

`Uncaught Error: React-router-component: No route matched! Did you define a NotFound route?`

Why react-router-component doesn't detected the context path, and where I need to configure it? I preferably want it to adjust at arbitrary path the application originates from, but hard coding it is also fine.

I read react-router-component documentation, but it didn't mention anything about the application context root.

Answer (score 0):

To get the application context into react-router you could pass configuration to the React app from the Java controller. In Java use `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` to get the context path, and pass this value to the React app.